# Is it possible to specify a negative date in the DATE command, that is, a date before the Birth of Christ?

Tags: command-line, date

I need to calculate the difference in days between two dates. With the date command we can convert dates to seconds and then calculate the difference in days.
For example:

```
$ echo $((($(date +%s --date "2023-10-21")-$(date +%s --date "1899-12-29"))/(3600*24)))
  45220
```

When the first date is positive all is good. When the first date is negative, it doesn't works. For example:

```
$ echo $((($( date +%s --date "-2022-05-10")-$(date +%s --date "1899-12-29"))/(3600*24)))
date: invalid date '-2022-05-10'
25570
```

On the other hand the DATE command can operate with negative dates:

```
$ date --date="3000 years ago"
Mon Nov 24 13:12:27 LMT -977
```

Else. As I see negative and positive dates have some differences.
For positive dates a year starts from 01 January. But for negative dates a year starts from 31 December:

First -Year: ...-29.12.01 -30.12.01 -31.12.01 **[0000]** +01.01.01 +02.01.01 +03.00.01... :First +Year

**About solution.**

This is needed to calculate numeric date values for **Libreoffice Calc** from its **zero date**. The zero date in Libreoffice is **1899-12-30**. But you have to count one day back from this date to get the right solution, to date **1899-12-29**. This happens because the number of seconds in a day is not constant for various reasons. For example from zero date **1899-12-30**:

```
$ echo "( $(date +%s --date 2023-10-21) - $(date +%s --date 1899-12-30) ) / (3600*24)" | bc -l
45219.97936342592592592592
```

We are 30 minutes 17 seconds short of getting the correct integer 45220(for my timezone).
For different dates and timezones, the discrepancy may be different.
"All these mean that calculations that rely on the **date** command should **never** be treated as **whole days**, but the **seconds** should be taken into consideration **also**", - **FedKad**.
A better calculation for Libreoffice's zero date may be something like this (rounding the floating point result):

```
$ echo "x=( $(date +%s --date 2023-10-21) - $(date +%s --date 1899-12-30) ) / (3600*24) + 0.5 ; scale=0; x/1" | bc -l
45220
```

Thanks **FedKad** for the answer.
Else: the date command doesn't recognize first 3 minutes 03 seconds for date 19-10-01 for some timezones(try " for i in {-1869875830..-1869875800}; do TZ=Asia/Istanbul date --date @$i; done ", - Egmont) and calculates zero year which is wrong; there is no year **0** (FredKad).

So "Use a tool dedicated for calendar day calculations", - **Egmont**.

"For dates after (**Gregorian**) **1600 AD** you could consider using [dateutils.ddiff](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dateutils.ddiff.1.html) ", – **Steeldriver**.

Check with [date calculating](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadd.html) online(FedKad).

P.S. To see time gaps for your country you can use "**zdump -v**" command. For example:
zdump -v Europe/Berlin, zdump -v America/New_York, zdump -v Iran etc.

Comment: I don't think the `date` command is capable of interpreting BC years correctly. The output of `date -d 'now - 2023 years'` is `Fri 24 Nov 0000 02:58:34 PM LMT` which is wrong; there is no year 0. Similarly `date -d 'now - 2024 years'` output is `Wed 24 Nov -001 03:00:16 PM LMT` which is again wrong.

Comment: And even the result of the first calculation in your question (45220) is not correct. Please, verify with https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=29&m1=12&y1=1899&d2=21&m2=10&y2=2023

Comment: Yeah there's lots of complications here - not least of which is whose calendar you are using. See for example [Old Style and New Style dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Style_and_New_Style_dates). For dates after (Gregorian) 1600 AD you could consider using [dateutils.ddiff](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dateutils.ddiff.1.html)

Comment: `date` thinks in seconds, and formats or parses the given time (expressed in seconds according to a fixed point that happened at the same moment all across the globe) (also note that it ignores leap seconds) according to the timezones database. It was not meant to do calendar days computations. If you try to trick it to do that (let's say, arbitrarily picking the opening midnight of both days), it might easily go wrong whenever a location changed its timezone, even if it's just a DST change, let alone if a bigger one. Use a tool dedicated for calendar day calculations.

Comment: Please consider accepting @fedkad answer as a solution to your question.

Comment: @stumblebee . Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the `date` command is capable of interpreting BC years correctly in the first place:

- The output of `date -d 'now - 2023 years'` is `Fri 24 Nov 0000 02:58:34 PM LMT` which is wrong; there is no year 0.
- Similarly `date -d 'now - 2024 years'` output is `Wed 24 Nov -001 03:00:16 PM LMT` which is again wrong.

---

Even the result of the first calculation in your question (`45220`) is not correct, as can be checked [online](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=29&m1=12&y1=1899&d2=21&m2=10&y2=2023) which returns `45221` days.

I have made some tests and seen that the `date` command does not seem to recognize the date 1910-01-01 as valid (at least for my timezone):

```
$ date --date "1910-10-01"
date: invalid date ‘1910-10-01’
```

It should be a Saturday as the `cal` command shows.

```
$ date --date "1910-09-30"
Fri 30 Sep 1910 12:00:00 AM IMT
$ date --date "1910-09-31"
date: invalid date ‘1910-09-31’
$ date --date "1910-10-01"
date: invalid date ‘1910-10-01’
$ date --date "1910-10-02"
Sun 02 Oct 1910 12:00:00 AM EET
```

The reason of this "missing day" (actually a missing time period of 3 minutes and 4 seconds due to timezone change) is explained in the comments by @egmont:

```
$ date --date "1910-09-30 23:59:59"
Fri 30 Sep 1910 11:59:59 PM IMT
$ date --date "1910-10-01 00:00:00"
date: invalid date ‘1910-10-01 00:00:00’
$ date --date "1910-10-01 00:01:00"
date: invalid date ‘1910-10-01 00:01:00’
$ date --date "1910-10-01 00:03:03"
date: invalid date ‘1910-10-01 00:03:03’
$ date --date "1910-10-01 00:03:04"
Sat 01 Oct 1910 12:03:04 AM EET
```

This is the reason of the "missing" day in your first calculation.

**Please note!** On my timezone, your calculation gives:

```
$ echo $((($(date +%s --date "2023-10-21")-$(date +%s --date "1899-12-29"))/(3600*24)))
45220
```

The above number is the "truncated" integer result of the floating point result of the division which is something like 45220.9562037... in my timezone. **Please, check the output of the following command on your system:**

```
$ echo "( $(date +%s --date 2023-10-21) - $(date +%s --date 1899-12-29) ) / (3600*24)" | bc -l
45220.95620370370370370370
```

A better calculation may be something like this (rounding the floating point result):

```
$ echo "x=( $(date +%s --date 2023-10-21) - $(date +%s --date 1899-12-29) ) / (3600*24) + 0.5 ; scale=0; x/1" | bc -l
45221
```

---

All these mean that calculations that rely on the `date` command should never be treated as whole days, but the seconds should be taken into consideration also.

---

You can use other tools:

- For example, **LibreOffice Calc** seems to correctly calculate the date (day) differences as can be seen from the screenshot below:

[image: Calc date diffs]

- As an alternative command line utility, you can use [datediff](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/dateutils.ddiff.1.html) as @steeldriver suggested. However, it does not support dates before 1601-01-01 ("*By design dates before 1601-01-01 are not supported.*"), let alone negative years:

```
$ dateutils.ddiff 1901-01-01 1601-01-01
-109572
$ dateutils.ddiff 1901-01-01 1600-12-31
ddiff: cannot make sense of `1600-12-31' using the given input formats
```

- The following Python code will display date differences (although it does not support negative years):

```
from datetime import date
print((date(2023,10,21)-date(1899,12,29)).days)
```

---

You should carefully consider the actual need behind your date calculations, especially for [dates when Gregorian calendar has no meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar).

Comment: Looks like you changed timezone and thus skipped a few minutes at midnight. Try this to print some timestamps, increasing by 1 second every time: `for i in {-1869875830..-1869875800}; do TZ=Asia/Istanbul date --date @$i; done`. And of course no one had 31 Sep.

Comment: Yes. You are right. There is no time period between `Fri 30 Sep 1910 11:59:59 PM IMT` and `Sat 01 Oct 1910 12:03:04 AM EET`. So there is no time like `Sat 01 Oct 1910 12:00:00 AM` :) Thanks for the clarification. And I guess the original poster has a similar timezone change sometime in the 20th century, so that the missing minutes result in losing a whole day after truncation.

Comment: @JungoBongo  Did you check the output of `echo "( $(date +%s --date 2023-10-21) - $(date +%s --date 1899-12-29) ) / (3600*24)" | bc -l` on your system? Please, update your question by adding the output you get from this command.

Comment: @FedKad. You can use "zdump" command to see time gaps: 
$ zdump -v Turkey | grep 1910 →
1910 UT = Fri Sep 30 23:59:59
1910 UT = Sat Oct  1 00:03:04